# OpenGL benchmark on iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm looking for a comparison of iPhone 3G / 3GS graphical systems (opengl) to the ones on a PC / MAC.

Google didn't help. Perhaps anybody here?

Comment: Are you looking for performance benchmarks?  Might as well compare a Ferrari to a bicycle.

Comment: @mikerobi - As I state in my answer, the performance differences are not as great as you would think.  While modern desktop GPUs tend to be much more powerful than mobile ones in most applications, in some cases mobile GPUs can surpass older desktop hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this might be more of a hardware question, there is enough that might influence the design of an OpenGL-based application here that I'll bite.

Using my Molecules application as a template, I benchmarked the rendering throughput of that running on iPhone 3G, iPad, and a 2nd generation MacBook Air (Nvidia GeForce 9400M).  For the MacBook, the numbers were generated from running the application in the Simulator with nothing else executing on the system:

```
iPhone 3G: 423,000 triangles / s
iPad: 1,830,000 triangles / s
MacBook Air: 2,150,000 triangles / s
```

You can grab the [code for the application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules) and try this yourself by enabling the RUN_OPENGL_BENCHMARKS define in SLSMoleculeGLViewController.  This causes structures to be rendered for 100 frames, then the total time measured and the rendering rate figured from the complexity of the model being shown.

Note that this is an OpenGL ES 1.1 application which is geometry-limited in its current state.  A fill-rate-limited application might have completely different performance characteristics, same as with one that uses OpenGL / OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders.

Aside from performance differences, the OpenGL command set differs between iOS and the Mac.  OpenGL ES cuts out a lot of the cruft that's built up in OpenGL over the years (immediate mode, etc.).  In general, OpenGL ES is a subset of OpenGL, so you can pretty much port something written for OpenGL ES to OpenGL without a lot of trouble.  OpenGL on the desktop also uses a newer version of GLSL for its shaders (1.4, I believe), so some of the commands supported there will not work on iOS devices.

Apple has more about platform-specific differences in their [Platform Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH106-SW1) section in the OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS.